# IDA： How to change the instructions displayed on the interface from arm to x86

Tags: architecture, x86, arm, ida

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGGa6.png)

The instruction in this picture is the arm instruction architecture, in fact I want to get the instruction of the X86 instruction architecture ,like movq movl cmpq addq..., what should I do？

Comment: when you examine an x86 program do you get x86 instructions?

Comment: That looks like x86(_64) to me. Why do you say it's ARM?

Comment: Really x86_ 64 assembly code, I was wrong. For example, for MOV instructions, why are there no movq and movl instructions? They are all mov instructions.

Comment: You're thinking of AT&T syntax for x86-64.  IDA uses Intel syntax, where operand-size is indicated by `mov dword ptr [rdi], 1234` if not implied by a register operand like in `mov [rdi], eax`.  (Specifically, it's a MASM-like flavour of Intel syntax, with weird use of `cs:` to mean RIP-relative.)  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info vs. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info .  If you want AT&T disassembly, use something like `objdump -d` with its default options (without `-Mintel`).  Or just get used to Intel syntax; it's what Intel manuals use anyway so it's good to know it.